# CSS vertically align LI's in middle

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have the following HTML where I need the LI elements to vertically display in the middle of the 21 pixel high UL area.  Here is my HTML...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .MenuBar
        {
            padding: 0px;
            border: 1px solid #036;
            height: 21px;
            font-size: 8pt;
        }
        .MenuBar li
        {
            display: inline;
            padding-left: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="MenuBar">
        <li>Link 1</li><li>Link 2</li><li>Link 3</li></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

How would one alter the above HTML to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I presume you are trying to make a horizontal rather than a vertical list, since you are setting the LI elements display type to "inline". So try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .MenuBar
    {
        padding: 0px;
        border: 1px solid #036;
        height: 21px;
        font-size: 8pt;
    }
    .MenuBar li
    {
        display: inline;
        line-height: 21px;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're after?

```
    .MenuBar li
    {
        display: inline;
        padding-left: 20px;
        line-height: 21px;
    }
```

Like Sarfraz, I'm not sure I totally understand the question.

Answer (score 2):

Add `line-height:21px` to `.MenuBar`

Answer (score 0):

Could not get exactly what you want but if you want to make the lists appear vertically, try this:

```
    .MenuBar li
    {
        display: block;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
```

Just change `display` property to `block` instead of `inline`. And this is the default behavior too.

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant and reliable way of doing it is to insert an assistent inline element into the `<li />` element as the 1st child, which height should be set to 100% (of its parent’s height, the `<li />`), and its vertical-align set to middle. To achieve this, you can put a `<span />`, but the most convenient way is to use li:after pseudo class.

```
.MenuBar li:before
{
    display: inline;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    content: '';
}
```

In this way you don't need to hard code a height value (21px or something). Refer to:
[CSS vertical alignment text inside li](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543859/css-vertical-alignment-text-inside-li/26122295#26122295)