# CSS vertical alignment text inside li

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am displaying number of  boxes in a row with fix height and width, generated from <li> tags.
now I need to align the text in the  vertical center.
The CSS vertical-align has no impact, maybe I am missing something???

I am not looking for tricks using (margin, padding, line-height), these will not work because some text are long and will break into two lines.

Please find the actual code:

### CSS code

```
ul.catBlock{
  width:960px; 
  height: 270px; 
  border:1px solid #ccc; 
}

ul.catBlock li{
  list-style: none; 
  float:left; 
  display:block; 
  text-align: center; 
  width:160px; 
  height: 100px;
}

ul.catBlock li a{ 
  display: block;  
  padding: 30px 10px 5px 10px; 
  height:60px;
}
```

### HTML code

```
<ul class="catBlock">
 <li><a href="#">IP Phone</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Dual SIM Switch Server</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">IP PBX</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 111):

Define the parent with `display: table` and the element itself with `vertical-align: middle` and `display: table-cell`.

Comment: This is from W3CSchool... Note: The values "inline-table", "run-in", "table", "table-caption", "table-cell", "table-column", "table-column-group", "table-row", "table-row-group", and "inherit" is not supported in IE7 and earlier. IE8 requires a !DOCTYPE. IE9 supports the values.

Comment: What about `<li>`s getting into a single row?

Comment: Also this is not CATO accessibility compliant if you are in fact NOT showing tabular data.

Comment: I know of the solutions, they are hacky at best, there is a reason why css3 and html5 are a thing now, and its because people were not satisfied with the previous iterations. I was just challenging your statement that "a bad workman blames his tools". IMO a truly bad workman never even questions the tools they are provided with.

Answer (score 94):

However many years late this response may be, anyone coming across this might just want to try

```
li {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Browser support for flexbox is far better than it was when @scottjoudry posted his response above, but you may still want to consider prefixing or other options if you're trying to support much older browsers. [caniuse: flex](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

Comment: This doesn't play nice with `list-style-image` in Chrome - the image disappears

Answer (score 63):

`line-height` is how you vertically align text. It is pretty standard and I don't consider it a "hack". Just add `line-height: 100px` to your `ul.catBlock li` and it will be fine.

In this case you may have to add it to `ul.catBlock li a` instead since all of the text inside the `li` is also inside of an `a`. I have seen some weird things happen when you do this, so try both and see which one works.

Comment: I have used line-height initially but when the content is long it will break into 2 lines and let's say 100px gap each line and wil make it look worse. is there any other way?

Comment: I think there is a way to have `vertical-align: middle` if you have `display: table-cell`. I have never used it though. Take a look here: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Comment: Great solution - I set the li 'line height' to be the same as my min-height, and the text is vertically aligned - at least close enough for a visual inspection. The 'table' solution above is certainly not semantic, and is hackish in nature. Any time we are doing that, we are increasing the chances of broken displays or quirky behavior somewhere in the responsive landscape.

Comment: Thanks! Works great on the <a> element! What a simple solution :-) Just tweak it to correct value and it centers vertically perfect!

Answer (score 16):

Surprisingly (or not), the `vertical-align` tool actually works best for this job. **Best of all, no Javascript is required.**

In the following example, I am positioning the `outer` class in the middle of the body, and the `inner` class in the middle of the `outer` class.

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/tLkSV/513/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <span></span><div class="outer">
        <span></span><div class="inner">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; }
#container {
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%; }
span { 
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; }
.outer {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; }
.inner {
    background: red;
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;    
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; }
```

Vertical align works by aligning the centers of elements that are next to each other. Applying vertical-align to a single element does absolutely nothing. If you add a second element that has no width but is the height of the container, your single element will move to vertically center with this no-width element, thus vertically centering it. The only requirements are that you set both elements to inline (or inline-block), and set their vertical-align attribute to `vertical-align: middle`.

*Note: You may notice in my code below that my `<span>` tag and `<div>` tag are touching. Because they are both inline elements, a space will actually add a space between the no-width element and your div, so be sure to leave it out.*

Comment: Fantastic,  it makes a good sense. //I can't vote your answer now because my min reputation should be 15.

Comment: For those of you looking for this technique applied directly to the question - http://jsfiddle.net/utGVt/385/

Answer (score 16):

In the future, this problem will be solved by flexbox. Right now the browser support is dismal, but it is supported in one form or another in all current browsers.

Browser support: http://caniuse.com/flexbox

```
.vertically_aligned {

    /* older webkit */
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;

    /* older firefox */
    display: -moz-box;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-pack: center;

    /* IE10*/
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;

    /* newer webkit */
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;

    /* Standard Form - IE 11+, FF 22+, Chrome 29+, Opera 17+ */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Background on Flexbox: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: At the time this question was asked I'm not sure this would have been a good answer but today we're seeing [~95% prefixed support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) so I certainly think this is a viable option.

Comment: If you wish the <li> elements to wrap (instead of being shrinked), add flex-wrap: wrap; at <ul> level

Comment: What element do I add this class too?

Answer (score 6):

There are no perfect answers provided here except Asaf's answer which doesn't provide any code nor any example, so I would like to contribute mine...

Inorder to make `vertical-align: middle;` work, you need to use `display: table;` for your `ul` element and `display: table-cell;` for `li` elements and than you can use `vertical-align: middle;` for `li` elements.

You don't need to provide any explicit `margins`, `paddings` to make your text vertically middle.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qg59r/)

```
ul.catBlock{
    display: table;
    width:960px; 
    height: 270px; 
    border:1px solid #ccc; 
}

ul.catBlock li {
    list-style: none;
    display: table-cell; 
    text-align: center; 
    width:160px; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}

ul.catBlock li a { 
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help since the only reason its been aligned vertically is because you forced it down with padding on the a tag

Comment: @Mr.Alien I will reiterate though that the only problem with this solution is that margin rules are ignored.

Answer (score 6):

As explained in here: https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/.

> As tested in the real practice, the most reliable yet elegant solution is to insert an assistent inline element into the `<li />` element as the 1st child, which height should be set to 100% (of its parent’s height, the `<li />`), and its `vertical-align` set to middle. To achieve this, you can put a `<span />`, but the most convenient way is to use `li:after` pseudo class.

Screenshot:
[image]

```
ul.menu-horizontal {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

ul.menu-horizontal:after {
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    float: none;
    display: block;
}

ul.menu-horizontal li {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
}

/* The magic happens here! */
ul.menu-horizontal li:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution for vertical align middle... for me it works like a charm

```
ul{display:table; text-align:center; margin:0 auto;}
li{display:inline-block; text-align:center;}
li.items_inside_li{display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this solution a try

#### Works best in most of the cases

you may have to use **div** instead of **li** for that

```css
.DivParent {
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid lime;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.verticallyAlignedDiv {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: normal;
}
.DivHelper {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="DivParent">
    <div class="verticallyAlignedDiv">
        <p>Isnt it good!</p>
     
    </div><div class="DivHelper"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why this need a divHelper to vertical-align? I saw it on another topic, but I can't understand why it doesn't align it self without another div..