# How to align vertically text inside li in css

Tags: css

I have an `<li>` tag which contains an `img` and text, and I want to align the contents of this `li` centered vertically. What is the best way to do this?

```
<ul id='menu'>
    <li>
        <img src='image/logout.png' width='40px' height='40px'>  
        <a href='index3.php?page=logout'>LOGOUT</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```css
ul#menu li {
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-right: 0;
    border-left: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 30px 0 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 30px 0 30px;
    border-radius: 0 30px 0 30px;

    /*Shadow*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);

    /*Gradient*/
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
}
```

[image]

Comment: this has been asked a gazzilion times before

Comment: I've tried it and it didn't work. it's only works on text. i need image and text inside <li>

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS vertical alignment text inside li](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543859/css-vertical-alignment-text-inside-li)

Comment: I've tried it and it didn't work....!

Answer (score 0):

You can add `style="vertical-align: middle;"` on the image tag to vertically center it with the text.

Comment: Take a look at this jsfiddle. Is this not the result you want? https://jsfiddle.net/zg3z4bgb/1/