# Why is my text not centered vertically on some devices?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem that I don't know how to solve. The text in the box is not centered vertically for me on some devices. On my computer, it is perfectly centered, but on my mobile phone, it is a little higher. Also this is my SCSS for this:

```
            .single-size{
                text-align: center;
                a{
                    padding: 1rem;
                    font-size: 2rem;
                    display: block;
                    border: .1rem solid #D8D8D8;
                    &.active{
                        background-color: $secondary;
                        border: .1rem solid $secondary;
                        color: #fff;
                    }
                }
            }
```

And my HTML:

```
<div class="single-size">
    <a href="#" class="attribute">XXL</a>
</div>
```

This is a picture from the computer:
[image: PC pic]

This is a picture from mobile:
[image: Mob pic]

Can someone explain me why is this happend?

Answer (score 0):

You need to align them vertically

```
          .single-size{
                text-align: center;
                align-items: center;
                display: flex;
                a{
                    padding: 1rem;
                    font-size: 2rem;
                    display: block;
                    border: .1rem solid #D8D8D8;
                    &.active{
                        background-color: $secondary;
                        border: .1rem solid $secondary;
                        color: #fff;
                    }
                }
            }
```

And check for margin in anchor tag,

put `margin: 0;` in anchor tag's css

Comment: I already tried that, still the same

Comment: You can [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543859/css-vertical-alignment-text-inside-li)